# When do $n$ ants in cyclic pursuit with constant velocity converge?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, proof-explanation

I'm reading a paper ([Ants, Crickets and Frogs in Cyclic Pursuit](http://www.cs.arizona.edu/%7Ealon/papers/frog.pdf)) and trying to understand one of the simpler results.

The following is a paraphrasing of the parts I'm using, but check the paper if more context is needed:

> Consider $n$ moving ants $\mathrm{x}_1(t)$ through $\mathrm{x}_n(t)$ in a vector space $\mathcal{L}$. Each ant $\mathrm{x}_i$ moves at all times in the direction of the ant $\mathrm{x}_{i-1}$ (and $\mathrm{x}_1 \to \mathrm{x}_n$) with constant velocity $v$.
>
> For $i = 1,...n$, define the initial conditions as $\mathrm{x}_i(0) = \xi_i$ and the following system of $n$ differential equations:
>
> $$\frac{d}{dt} \mathrm{x}_i(t) = v \ \frac{\mathrm{x}_{i-1}(t) - \mathrm{x}_i(t)}{||\mathrm{x}_{i-1}(t) - \mathrm{x}_i(t)||}$$
>
> We can construct an equivalent model in barycentric coordinates by defining
>
> $$\mathrm{y}_i(t) = \mathrm{x}_{i-1}(t) - \mathrm{x}_i(t)$$
>
> Then for $i = 1,...,n$, we have $\mathrm{y}_i(0) = \xi_{i-1} - \xi_i$ and the following system of equations:
>
> $$\frac{d}{dt} \mathrm{y}_i(t) = v \left(\frac{\mathrm{y}_{i-1}(t)}{||\mathrm{y}_{i-1}(t)||} - \frac{\mathrm{y}_i(t)}{||\mathrm{y}_i(t)||} \right)$$
>
> For this system, we can prove the following:
>
> $\textbf{Lemma 1}$ The difference vectors $\mathrm{y}_i(t)$ have the following properties:
>
> 1. $\sum \mathrm{y}_i = 0$
> 2. $\frac{d}{dt} ||\mathrm{y}_i|| = (\cos \alpha_i - 1) v$
>
> Where $\alpha_i$ is the angle between $\mathrm{y}_i$ and $\mathrm{y}_{i-1}$.
>
> $\textbf{Proof:}$ The first part follows by definition and the second comes from projecting $\mathrm{y}_{i-1}$ onto $\mathrm{y}_i$.
>
> Call $T$ the termination time where all ants collide and define $Y(t) = \sum_i ||\mathrm{y}_i(t)||$.

Then comes the part I'm most curious about. They claim

> If the speeds are constant and equal, Lemma $1$ part 2 implies that $T \le Y(0)/v$.

I think this works by summing both sides of the second equality to get

$$\sum_i \frac{d}{dt}||\mathrm{y}_i|| = v \sum_i (\cos \alpha_i - 1) \le -v$$

which would prove the claim, but the inequality is where I get stuck.

I'm thinking we can bound the sum somehow by using the fact that $\sum_i \alpha_i \ge 2\pi$, but I'm not quite sure how to do this.

Edit: It appears this claim is false as pointed out by @stewbasic.

---

I'd still like to get answers for the following:

1. **A general bound for the termination time $T$.**
2. **Under what conditions do the ants collide simultaneously?**

For simultaneity, a sufficient condition is fine provided it covers the specific case of cube. For example, if a cycle of $n$ ants all start a constant distance $\mathrm{y}(0) = ||\mathrm{y}_i(0)||$ from their pursuer and prey and all start the same distance $d$ from their centroid, is this enough to ensure simultaneity of collision? If it simplifies things, the time bound need only apply to cases that satisfy the sufficient condition for simultaneity.

**Specific case**: Consider $8$ ants on the corners of a unit cube with pursuit cycle given by

$$(0,0,0) \to (1,0,0) \to (1,1,0) \to (1,1,1) \to (1,0,1) \to (0,0,1) \to (0,1,1) \to (0,1,0)$$

I'd ideally like to get the bound $T \le 2/v$, but even $T \le 8/v$ would acceptable. The actual value is about $1.96$, which I can get from simulation where their convergence path looks like this:

[image: Mathematica graph]

Here's an animated version I created:

[image: Animated graph]

Edit:

As @VictorZurkowski points out, the proof of Theorem $1$ includes a (not very strict) bound on $T$ which reduces in the constant velocity case to

$$T \le \frac{Y(0)}{v\left(1 - \cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{m}\right)\right)}$$

where $m$ is the number of survivors. For the cube case with unit speed, this becomes

$$T \le \frac{Y(0)}{1\left(1 - \cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{8}\right)\right)} = \frac{8}{\left(1 - \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right)} = 8\left(2 + \sqrt{2}\right) \approx 27.3137$$

Using symmetry, I think I could get this down to $2 \left(2+\sqrt{2}\right) \approx 6.82843$.

All of the $\alpha_i$ follow one of these two curves where the $y$-axis is in degrees and the $x$-axis is $t$ in percent of of $T$ (at 100% they converge). We can see that they converge to the planar case where $\alpha_i = \frac{\pi}{4} = 45^{\circ}$

[image: Alphas]

I believe the planar case is worst case in terms of convergence time and [this website](https://jasmcole.com/2014/07/15/ant-ics/) has some nice bounds for regular polygons with unit area. If my calculations are correct, an octagon with unit length sides would have path length $2\sqrt{4+3\sqrt{2}} \approx 5.742$.

[To be revised and continued...]

Comment: You should include the definition that $\alpha_i$ is the angle between $\mathbf y_i$ and $\mathbf y_{i-1}$.

Comment: Yes, of course. Thank you. I will edit it.

Comment: I believe $\sum_i\alpha_i$ is exactly $2\pi$ if the $\alpha_i$ are taken with signs. Then maybe the inequality $\cos\alpha\ge1-\frac12\alpha^2$ (from the Taylor series) can help bound the $\sum_i(\cos\alpha_i-1)$ term.

Comment: That is that case if the ants are in a plane, but certainly not necessarily true in more dimensions.

Comment: There is no reason to have a simultaneous collision in general. Imagine the scenario when ant 1 is moving towards ant 2, which is nearby, while ant 2 is moving towards ant 3 that initially is far away on the ray going from ant 2 to ant 1. Clearly, ant 1 will intercept ant 2 in a harsh collision even if they don't stay on one line all the time. There is no a priori reason why the situation like that won't eventually arise even from some innocently looking generic initial setting if the pursuit order is fancy...

Comment: @fedja Thanks. Given the condition that that $||y_i(0)||$ is a constant (they start out the same distance from each other), is simultaneity assured?

Comment: No. Imagine the same story: ant 1 going towards ant 2, which is one unit to the right from it, then a long chain of ants going to the left, and then another long chain going back to the right.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be not true. Consider the case where the ants start on successive vertices of a regular $n$-gon (in the plane). By symmetry, their positions will always form a regular $n$-gon, so
$$
  \alpha_i=\frac{2\pi}n.
$$
Now Lemma 1 part 2 gives
$$
  \frac{d}{dt}Y(t)=-kv
$$
where
$$
  k=n\left(1-\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}n\right)\right).
$$
Thus $T=Y(0)/(kv)$. Now $k\to0$ as $n\to\infty$ (asymptotically it is $\frac{2\pi^2}n$) so we can choose $n$ with $k<1$. Explicitly if $n=20$ then $k\approx0.97887$ (see [wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5B%7Bn,N%5Bn*(1-Cos%5B2*Pi%2Fn%5D)%5D%7D,%7Bn,1,30%7D%5D)). Then $T>Y(0)/v$.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to check closely to make sure I'm not missing something. The text explicitly says "the only conconfigurations leading to equality are those for which $C(0)$ is a perfect polygon" so it would seem rather sloppy of them for this exact case to be a counterexample.

Comment: Their claim also doesn't make sense intuitively. As $n\rightarrow\infty$ their bound for $T$ goes to a constant, but the ants get closer and closer to just moving along the circumference of the circle at speed $v$. It's possible that this case is the worst, so the bound should be $T\leq Y(0)/(kv)$ (haven't thought carefully about it).

Comment: I wonder about regular $n$-gons of fixed radius $||x_i||$ rather than fixed edge length $||y_i||$. According to [this](https://jasmcole.com/2014/07/15/ant-ics/), unit area $n$-gons path lengths approach $n \pi^{-3/2}$. So $X(0) = n$ means in the limit $T = X(0)/(v\pi^{3/2})$.

Comment: I meant sending $n\to\infty$ with $Y(0)$ fixed, which is roughly the same as fixing $\|x_i\|$ (either way the initial configuration approaches a particular circle). Why are you dividing $X(0)$ by the path length $s_n$? $T$ should be $s_n/v$ which is asymptotically proportional to $n$.

Comment: @AlexisOlson for your edited question, I think you also need to specify the order of the ants - ie which vertex is being targeted by which?

Comment: The cycle can fairly easily be inferred from the image, but I'll edit it in a more explicitly when I get back on a computer.

Answer (score 1):

In Section 1 (the one about Ants), Theorem 1 says:
"Termination must therefore occur before [$(\cos(2\pi /m)-1) \int_0^t \min v_i(s)\;ds$] assumes the value $-\sum ||y_i(0)||$ ." (1)

In case of constant speed, this statement translates to $T \le (1-\cos(\frac{2\pi}{m}))^{-1}\frac{Y(0)}{v}$, where $m$=number of survivors by termination time.

In particular, @stewbasic basic example does not contradict the statement, since in that case the number of survivors by temination time is $n$.

In your example of 8 points at the vertices of a cube, whether $T\le 2$ depends on the speed $v$ that you are considering.

$\mathbf{\text{Note}}$: To prove (1), Bruckstein et alt. use that $\alpha_i \ge \frac{2\pi}{m}$ for some $i$, which does not seem to follow from the result they quote. i.e.: it is not clear that the proof of the bound for $T$ is without gaps.

Comment: I meant $T \le 2$ for unit speed. In other words, $T \le 2/v$.

Comment: After a second look, there is an obvious mis-statement in Lemma 3, Section V of the paper you refer to. Where it says "$\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \le 2\pi$" it should say "$\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \ge 2\pi$", from where it follows that $\alpha_i \ge \frac{2\pi}{m}$ for some $i$.

Comment: The statement I claimed was false was that $T\leq Y(0)/v$, made near the end of page 9.

Comment: I missed that line. I stopped at the top of page 8. $T\leq Y(0)/v$ is wrong, as @stewbasic example shows.